# view parent table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Several table that stores main information about my Existence (parent tables ) and Each table have few children Table that hold other information about Existence.

Each child table have a foreign key that refers to his parent table.

I like when call a child table, I get the name of the parent table.

Comment: Please provide some more information about your schema (table structure) and the things you already tried and your actual problem.

Comment: I don't think you really understand what you are asking.  Just because a table has a foreign key to another table doesn't necessarily mean it is a child of that other table.  It simply means that it relates in some way to that other table.  It is possible to examine the MySql system tables to determine what you are asking--but unless you are building some kind of system tool, it is simply more useful to know your data and work with it directly.  Show us what you have done so far, and we'll see where we can take you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to retrieve the create query of the child table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE child_table;
```

The result is one row with two columns.

Parse the content of the second column ("Create Table") with a regex to get the parent table name:

```
/CONSTRAINT(.+?)REFERENCES\s\`(.+?)\`/si
```

The value of the second group will be the parent table name.